# GORM hooks - Cannot get the ID when update multiple rows

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the update code like this:

```
db.Model(&models.DailyPlan{}).
   Where("daily_plan_id IN ?", dailyPlanIds).
   Updates(updateClause).Error
```

and hooks:

```
func (d *DailyPlan) AfterSave(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
   // blah blah
   return
}
```

But when I run the update code above, in my hooks, I cannot get the ID (`daily_plan_id`) (only the fields in the `updateClause` have data).

How can I get the ID that I send in `dailyPlanIds`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set/Get` based on [here](https://gorm.io/docs/settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can query the records using Where() and when updating pass the pointer of the records to the Model(), so that the hooks can fire and and you can get the ID

```
// get plans
plans := []models.DailyPlan{}
db.Model(&models.DailyPlan{}).
   Where("daily_plan_id IN ?", dailyPlanIds).
   Find(&plans).Error

// update plans
db.Model(plans).
    Updates(updateClause).Error
```